# sensor fusion of 2 Points using message_filters

Tags: ros, sensor-fusion, message-filters, geometry-msgs, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I would like to write a nod that does some sensor fusion. The node should subscribe 2 Topics of type geometry_msgs::Point

if the two messages have the approximate same time_stamp simple the median should be calculated.

Now I would like to use [ros_message_filters_indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) and in particular the [approximate_message filter algorithm](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters/ApproximateTime).

As in [ros_message_filters_indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters), this code compiles for me:

```
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> image1_sub(nh, "image1", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> image2_sub(nh, "image2", 1);

  typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> MySyncPolicy;
  // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
  message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), image1_sub, image2_sub);
```

Now I would like to do that with Point messages:

```
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point> image1_sub(nh, "image1", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point> image2_sub(nh, "image2", 1);

  typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<geometry_msgs::Point, geometry_msgs::Point> MySyncPolicy;
  // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
  message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), image1_sub, image2_sub);
```

This code however does not build and gives a massive error message:

```
In file included from /hri/localdisk/markus/ros-alex/src/point_fusion/include/point_fusion/point_fusion_node.h:20:0,
                 from /hri/localdisk/markus/ros-alex/src/point_fusion/src/point_fusion_node.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h: In instantiation of ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::checkInterMessageBound() [with int i = 0; M0 = geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >; M1 = geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType]’:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:218:29:   required from ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0; M0 = geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >; M1 = geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >; M2 = message_filters::NullType; M3 = message_filters::NullType; M4 = message_filters::NullType; M5 = message_filters::NullType; M6 = message_filters::NullType; M7 = message_filters::NullType; M8 = message_filters::NullType; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:5:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 0; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > >; typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type = ros::MessageEvent<const geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/indigo/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:290:138:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > >; F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > >; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Point_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293529/sensor-fusion-of-2-points-using-message_filters/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2018-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

--> Solved my  own problem

Point is not working PointStamped is required!

```
  point_1_topic_ = nh.param("point_fusion/point_1_topic", std::string("/turtlebot3/ball_tracking/first_ball_state/position"));
  point_2_topic_ = nh.param("point_fusion/point_2_topic", std::string("/ball_tracking_depth/first_ball_state"));


  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PointStamped> image1_sub(nh, "image1", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PointStamped> image2_sub(nh, "image2", 1);

  typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<geometry_msgs::PointStamped, geometry_msgs::PointStamped> MySyncPolicy;
  // ApproximateTime takes a queue size as its constructor argument, hence MySyncPolicy(10)
  message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), image1_sub, image2_sub);
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) with karma: 311 on 2018-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0